# PendingIntent.getBroadcast cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-studio

I am writing a widget in android studio 0.89 targeting API level 20.  In my AppWidgetProvider, I am trying to create a pending intent to respond to a button being pressed.  My problem is that the IDE is not recognizing any method in PendingIntent.  Here is my code:

```
@Override public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widdlewidget_layout);

    Intent wifiIntent = new Intent(context, WiddleWidget.class);
    wifiIntent.setAction(WIFI_ACTION);

    ctx = context;

    PendingIntent pi = new PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0 , wifiIntent, 0);

}
```

The issue, lies on the line where I am creating pi.   Any help is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Should you remove _new_ when calling static methods - and just use _PendingIntent.getBroadcast(...)_?

Comment: yes....yes you should.  that fixed it.  thanks!

Comment: @ dlucci I added an answer with explanation, that will help in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Small Mistake

Just remove new keyword from here

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0 , wifiIntent, 0);
```

**Explanation :**

You cannot use **new** keyword with **PendingIntent** because it is a **singleton** class. Singleton means these class is with **private** **constructor**.